# Procedure returning new poly object

Tags: pass-by-reference, pascal

I am working on an assignment in Pascal writing a polynomial data type.  The biggest problem I'm having is when I try to use the procedure setCoeff(var p : poly; n : integer; coeff : real) it returns a new poly object with a coefficient only for index n, or x^n.  How do I keep the other values in tact and set the new coefficient with the procedure?  I have tried many things out of desparation, but these are 2 methods I used:

```
procedure setCoeff(var p : poly; n : integer; coeff : real);
{ prints error and halts if n < 0 or n > MAX_DEGREE; setting the coefficient of a term to zero where n >= 0 and n <= MAX_DEGREE will result in that term becoming or remaining non-existent }

var i : integer;

Begin
if n < 0 then
Begin
        writeln('Error - illegal coefficient; program halted');
    Halt(0);
End;
if n > MAX_DEGREE then
Begin
        writeln('Error - illegal coefficient; program halted');
    Halt(0);
End;
p[n] := coeff;
End;
End;
```

-and-

```
procedure setCoeff(var p : poly; n : integer; coeff : real);
{ prints error and halts if n < 0 or n > MAX_DEGREE; setting the coefficient of a term to zero where n >= 0 and n <= MAX_DEGREE will result in that term becoming or remaining non-existent }

var i : integer;

Begin
if n < 0 then
Begin
        writeln('Error - illegal coefficient; program halted');
    Halt(0);
End;
if n > MAX_DEGREE then
Begin
        writeln('Error - illegal coefficient; program halted');
    Halt(0);
End;
p[n] := coeff;
for i := MAX_DEGREE downto 0 do
Begin
getCoeff(p,i,coeff);
if coeff <> 0.0 then
    p[i] := coeff;
End;
End;
```

I know arrays are passed by reference, but it seems to be resetting the values of the array every time I run setCoeff(...).  This is the top part of my data type, including how it is declared:

```
unit
polynomial;

interface

uses
    Math;

const
MAX_DEGREE = 1000;

type
poly = Array[0..MAX_DEGREE] of Real;

var
coeff: Real;
degree : Integer;
```

Comment: 1. What is the `poly` type? How is it declared? 2. Do you really use both of these procedures? How exactly do you use them, given that they've got identical names? Or did you mean you had tried one, then the other?

Comment: I actually just thought about that.  My fault.  I should have specified.  I'll edit my original post

Comment: and no, I think I left my program using the first one, but I've tried so many different things.  I've never used Pascal before, so this is all very foreign to me.

Comment: Well, your first one worked for me in a simple test program in Borland Pascal 7.0. I called it twice, for two different members, and after the second call my `poly` variable retained both coefficients I had specified with `setCoeff`. How do you use the procedure? Also, how do you establish that previously set coefficients are not kept intact?

Comment: My professor provided a sample program to run, but I've tried several things.  My own test is: 
`program testPoly2;
uses polynomial;
var
p1,p2,result : poly;
coeff : real;
Begin
setCoeff(p1,1000,2.0);
setCoeff(p1,0,3.0);
writeln(getDegree(p1));
writeln(toString(p1));
getCoeff(p1,1000,coeff);
writeln(coeff);
getCoeff(p1,0,coeff);
writeln(coeff);
End.`

After running that though, it seems that the problem may actually be in my `function getDegree(p : poly):integer`

Comment: Yeah, I got it.  It was a few things, but after you said it worked, I looked at that code more closely.  One thing, I keep forgetting that in pascal, `getDegree := someInt;` is not like a [tag:Java] `return someInt;` so it kept returning the wrong value. Thanks, @AndriyM, for your help.  I feel like learning Pascal, I'm pretty far from home.

Comment: Ah, I think I get it. In Java, `return someInt;` both sets the return value and terminates the function, while in Pascal, `funcName := someInt;` merely sets the return value but doesn't exit the function. Could indeed be confusing to someone not just new to Pascal but with a different background too. Glad you figured that out, happy to be of help!